# Printing a path to the tree's node as a list

Tags: python, list, tree, binary-tree

I'm going insane a bit.

My goal is very simple. In a binary tree, give a node and return a path to this node as a list. 
There is a number of implementations available.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49227659/10405306) is one of the best and most straighforward:

```
def path(root, k):
    if not root:
        return []
    if root.val == k:
        return [root.val]
    res = path(root.left, k)
    if res:
        return [root.val] + res
    res = path(root.right, k)
    if res:
        return [root.val] + res
    return []
```

For pure educational reasons, I decided to rewrite it with a helper function in which I pass an empty list and recursively add elements to it.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def path2Node2(self, root, node2):
        if not root:
            return None

        def _helper(root, node, paths):
            if not root:
                return []
            if root.val == node.val:
                paths.append(root.val)
                return paths
            return _helper(root.left, node, paths + [root.val])
            return _helper(root.right, node, paths + [root.val])


        return _helper(root, node2, [])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = TreeNode(10)
    l.left = TreeNode(8)
    l.right = TreeNode(2)
    l.left.left = TreeNode(3)
    l.left.right = TreeNode(5)
    l.right.left = TreeNode(4)
    print(l.path2Node2(l, l.left))
```

It works if I pass the root node (*print(l.path2Node2(l, l)*).

It works if I pass the left child (*print(l.path2Node2(l, l.left))*)

But if I pass l.left.right or l.right.left, it returns [].

I cannot figure it out for the last few hours. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're solving today's CodeSignal challenge. Here's my Python3 solution. Hope it helps.

```
#
# Binary trees are already defined with this interface:
# class Tree(object):
#   def __init__(self, x):
#     self.value = x
#     self.left = None
#     self.right = None
def findCommonValues(t1, t2):
    def dfs(node:Tree, vals:list, comparison:dict=None):
        """Run a depth-first search on the tree by passing the root. If comparison is passed, then it
        is used to determine if we should add the value of node to the vals list. Otherwise, always
        add value to the vals list."""
        if not node:
            return
        if node.left:
            dfs(node.left, vals, comparison)
        if comparison is None or node.value in comparison:
            vals.append(node.value)
        if node.right:
            dfs(node.right, vals, comparison)

    # Create an empty list and use it to gather all the values from the first Tree
    vals = []
    dfs(t1, vals)
    # This line coverts my list to a dict, where each item in the list is a key, and the val is 
    # arbitrary (it will just be an incremented int here). This way, we can search for previous values
    # with constant run time.
    comparison = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(vals)}
    # Reset the list and process the 2nd Tree
    vals = []
    dfs(t2, vals, comparison)
    # Now the vals list has what we're looking for, thanks to line 17 in dfs
    return vals
```

For those looking at this in the future, [here](https://app.codesignal.com/challenge/6ZAh6MgWdxTMKhACH) is a link to the challenge on CodeSignal (formerly CodeFights).

Comment: Thank you! I'm not using CodeSignal (mainly CodeWars and LeetCode). I rewrote mine but it doesn't still help: if root.left: return _helper(root.left, node, paths + [root.val])
                                    if root.right: return _helper(root.right, node, paths + [root.val])

Answer (score 0):

So, here is the answer to my own question.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def path2Node2(self, root, node2):
        if not root:
            return []

        def _helper(root, node, paths):
            if not root:
                return []
            if root.val == node.val:
                paths.append(root.val)
                return paths
            l = _helper(root.left, node, paths + [root.val])
            r =  _helper(root.right, node, paths + [root.val])
            if l: return l
            if r: return r

        return _helper(root, node2, [])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = TreeNode(10)
    l.left = TreeNode(8)
    l.right = TreeNode(2)
    l.left.left = TreeNode(3)
    l.left.right = TreeNode(5)
    l.right.left = TreeNode(4)
    print(l.path2Node2(l, l.right))
```

I've added two lines:

```
if l: return l
if r: return r
```

But still don't understand what the difference is with my original approach.